# ViewPager вертикальные жесты

Tags: gestures, android-viewpager, android

У меня в элементе viewpager(реализация криса бейнса pulltorefresh) горизонтальная прокрутка страниц, с этим никаких проблем. Но мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при прокрутке вниз вызывалась другая activity, пытался сделать через gesturedetector, но он конфликтует с горизонтальным pulltorefresh, то есть либо одно, либо другое детектирует жесты

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наследуйте от исходной либы свой класс и в нем перекройте (`@Overridden`) обработчик жестов исходной либы.

Comment: Дело в том, что там сложная структура этого метода и просто так его не получается перекрыть. А возможно перекрытие с условиями? Что-то типа, если (условие), то использовать мой метод, а не библиотечный

Comment: Да.

if (condition) {
// own implementation
} else {
super.method();
}